# S3 access denied when making API call

Tags: amazon-web-services, dart, amazon-s3, aws-amplify

```
Future<void> retrieveDecks() async {
  try {
    Future<StorageListResult<StorageItem>> result = Amplify.Storage.list(
      path: 'public/deck',
    ).result;

    result.then((result) {
      List<StorageItem> items = result.items;
      print(items);
    });
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
  }
}
```

This is the function which is supposed to return a list of all the files present inside the `public/deck` folder. But when I call this function I am getting the error `S3 access denied when making API call`. I have tried giving s3full access to the IAM user but didn't work.

The code should return me a list of all the files but it doesn't work.

Comment: Assuming there's no S3 bucket policy on this bucket denying access, then either the credentials you're using aren't what you think they are or they aren't associated with an IAM principal that has S3FullAccess.

Comment: Did u solved this problem? i have the same problem on android 
but the weird thing its working on iOS